# Reset div value after toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I'm toggling between two divs to display who's turn it is in a tic tac toe game with this block of code

```
function whosTurn() {
    container.addEventListener('click', () => {
        firstturn.style.display = (
            firstturn.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none");
        secondturn.style.display = (
            secondturn.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none");
    })
}
whosTurn()
```

And I've come up with this to reset the div to display #firstturn when a reset button is clicked

```
function resetDiv() {
    reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($('#secondturn').length > 0) {
                $('#secondturn').replaceWith($('#firstturn'));
            }
        })

    })
}
resetDiv()
```

But that doesn't seem to work when i'm trying to .replaceWith "#firstturn" , but when I create a new different div and put it in firstturns place (just as a test) it does work.

I'm not sure if something in the first block of code is causing it, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not too sure but I think you don't need `if ($('#secondturn').length > 0)` since jQuery does not return null if no element is found

Comment: The document ready inside the click handler is unnecessary.  The page is already in the DOM by the time they click the element.

Comment: true and true, i removed both and it still works the same, thank u

Answer (score 0):

instead of replacing, you just have to do the show/hide logic (show first, hide second).

But I would highly recommend working with classes or data-attributes and do the styling with css. Let me know if you need help on this.